# How to use Vue JS with Wordpress using NPM?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, vue.js, npm

## **What is the best way to use Vue JS (by installing NPM) and import `vue` module into Wordpress `HTML` template together ?**

There are lots of approaches to do so, but all of them have their own Cons and Pros.

E.g. using CDN Vue js:

Advantages:

- It is straightforward to use.
- Ability to do simple interactive stuff and DOM handling.

Disadvantages:

- You are not able to use `<template>` tag in Vue.
- Not ability to use `scoped` css/scss styles.
- No way to use other Node modules like Webpack and other stuff.
- The code can be more messy.

[edited]: I don't want SPA page with Wordpress. I just want to manage components and repetitive codes and separate them into componenets.

Edited:
Here's the solution I've accomplished. I"ll appriciate it if someone pulls request.
https://github.com/ImAli7/vuepress

Answer (score 1):

I have created themes which uses VueJS with build process. I use a starter theme called [sage](https://roots.io/sage/) which has been created by [roots.io](https://roots.io/sage/) team.

Sage is introduced as "*WordPress starter theme with a modern development workflow*" and it is rightly does so. They have a setup "[JavaScript DOM-Based routing](https://roots.io/docs/sage/9.x/compiling-assets/#theme-assets)" which essentially enables you to run specific scripts on specific pages.

This comes very handy when using vueJS. You can go through [this particular post](https://discourse.roots.io/t/adding-vue-js-to-sage-9-dependencies-and-approach/9644) where they have discussed on how to add vuejs as a dependency.

It has browsersync and hot-module-reload which updates your chnages without reloading. You can develop using `yarn start` and once you want to build the production version of your theme you simply run `yarn build:production`.

In my theme I had to create multiple components which werent directly connected to each other but I added [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to manage my state and update the components using `mapAction` and `mapGetter`.

You won't be able to achive this with CDN. Though it comes with its hassel of using NPM but its a workflow which also gives you the ability to use VueJS to its full potential.

> I have also written a blog which explains how I used Github Actions to push my updated code to production or staging server. You can read it here - https://bhanusingh.in/deploying-sagewordpress-starter-theme-to-your-host-using-github-actions

Comment: Thanks a lot for your recommendation. Sage workflow is a great one and it becomes more handy where Blade template engine comes to play. However, the way I prefer is not to use these kinds of workflows and frameworks. I just want a way of How Can I import `Vue` module into my `HTML` wordpress theme. My current project is a small-sized one and there's no need for huge frameworks. I consider Sage for future, though. Thanks again :D